# Cannot ping any device from desktop running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS over wired network

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ping, ubuntu-16.04

I have a desktop (A) that is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and am trying to connect it to a welding controller (B) that we are trying to control. The two computers are directly connected using an Ethernet cable. (A) has an IP of `192.168.0.2` and (B) has an IP of `192.168.0.1` and the whole network is offline. Ubuntu network-manager shows that there is a local network connected but when I try to ping (B) from (A) I get `Destination Host Unreachable`.

Since (B) does not have a keyboard or the ability to ping (A), I have connected my MacBook to the network via a simple Ethernet switch with the IP of `192.168.0.3`. From my MacBook I can ping (B) just fine, but cannot ping (A) and I also cannot ping my MacBook from (A).

Using `arp -a` on (A) I can see both the MacBook and (B) but the `arp` entries are listed as incomplete. To top it all off, this whole connection issue seems to fix itself and I can ping everything just fine. But by the time I turn around, it's back to not working again.

Output of `ifconfig`:

```
enp0s25    Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr: 48:4d:7e:86:86
            inet addr:192.168.0.2 Bcast:192.168.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
            inet6 addr: f280::fff6:5a3e:a7cf:84c1/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
            RX packets:401 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:662 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
            RX bytes:139562 (138.5 KB) TX bytes:68262 (68.2 KB)
            Interrupt:20 Memory:f7f00000-f7f20000
lo          Link encap:Local Loopback
            inet addr: 127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
            inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
            UP LOOPBACK RUNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
            RX packets:23100 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:23100 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
            RX bytes:1723936 (1.7 MB) TX bytes:1723936 (1.7 MB)
```

Output of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtg 65536 qdisc nonqueue state UNKOWN group default qlen 1 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4*;4d:7e:ea:86:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.2/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp0s25
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::fff6:5a3e:a7cf:84c1/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of `ip link`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue UNKOWN mode DEFAULT group DEFAULT qlen 1 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT droup default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:4d:7e:ea:86:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Any help with this is much appreciated as I have been battling with it for about a week…

---

**UPDATE (9/28/17)**

So the fix that was working (see answer below about updating the Intel driver) is now no longer working and so I am back to square one of not knowing what is going on. I tried re-installing the driver just to make sure it had not gotten corrupted and that didn't help. So once again, any light that can be shed on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

According to this post on AskUbuntu (https://askubuntu.com/questions/522967/ubuntu-upgrades-break-ethernet-connection),
the issue is that an update to the kernel broke the driver for the Intel i217-lm ethernet device that is built into the computer. The solution is to download the most recent driver from Intel (see link below for download site) and install it. It's working now and hopefully it keeps working.

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCIe-Intel-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Connections-Under-Linux-?product=60019